# ASUS Laptop Move from HDD to SSD with original windows 7 and OEM Partition

Tags: windows, ssd, uefi, clone, asus-laptop

**my laptop:**
ASUS; Windows 7 Home edition sp1 2009 original; 25 GB partition for Windows OEM for factory recovery; MBR 700GB HDD Drive.
HDD has bad sectors: over 40KB per partition.
But Windows currently works well.

**summary:**
I got a 1TB SSD and I want to move to it since these bad sectors have made so many troubles for me, but I prefer to preserve the HDD as well since it still works. I also want to preserve my Windows 7 since it is original and I do not want to pay for a new Windows.

**Questions:**
To do so, I have many questions:

1. Image or clone?(I personally prefer image backup as it is reusable)
   since I want to preserve the existing HDD and I heard that cloning can cause conflict between two drives due to signature, but others said that this conflict can be solved. which one is true?
   1b. if I use backup, since I installed some software on another partition with different letter, is it possible to change the letter of the partitions then the software works?
2. I want to have my OEM Windows partition on the new SSD as well, then if necessary, I would be able it install the factory version. Yet, the problem is that: 2a. How can I make and introduce a new OEM partition to BIOS? 2b. Cloning is the only possible solution or taking an image would also be still possible?  2c. Can I take an image from the OEM windows drive and then reuse it further in the case of failing storage drives?
3. the essential problem hear is bad sectors! should I do “chkdsk” and then do cloning or imaging? (I am afraid that “chkdsk” cleans essential files of Windows! since it happened to me just recently)
4. Is it possible to verify our taken image or not?
5. UEFI or MBR? My HDD is in MBR. I do not know whether my original Windows 7 supports UEFI or not, but the HDD obviously was initially formatted as MBR. 5a. Is converting to UEFI worth it? (I want to do so for upcoming OS and its reliability due to duplicating drive addresses[especially in SSD] & etc) 5b. Is it possible to convert the SSD from MBR to UEFI safely? if yes, which application have you offered (I heard of Easeus and Minitool)? 5c. Does my OEM will work under UEFI?

Comment: There are questions here on this site already about imaging and dealing with bad sectors on those. Also, we require each post here to have only a single question, so that a single answer can be given and selected. Please indicate the research you have done and what you have tried so far, and focus your post to a single question.